# R - which and which.max fusion

Tags: r

I have a simple question, how could I use `which` and `which.max` at the same time.

I would like to select the maximum `epnum` for the row `id == B13639J2`. 
I need to retreive the `row number` because I need to make some manual changes to the variable.

So max `epnum` of row `id == 'B13639J2'`

```
           id   epnum start
95528 B13639J2     1     0
95529 B13639J2     2   860
95530 B13639J2     3  1110
95531 B13639J2     4  1155
95532 B13639J2     5  1440
```

I was wondering how I could simply do something like

```
dta[which(dta$id == 'B13639J2' & which.max(dta$epnum)), ]
```

Finally then, I need to delete the spotted row.

Thanks.

The data

```
dta = structure(list(id = c("B13639J1", "B13639J1", "B13639J1", "B13639J1", 
"B13639J1", "B13639J1", "B13639J1", "B13639J1", "B13639J2", "B13639J2", 
"B13639J2", "B13639J2", "B13639J2"), epnum = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), start = c(420, 425, 435, 540, 570, 
1000, 1310, 1325, 0, 860, 1110, 1155, 1440)), .Names = c("id", 
"epnum", "start"), row.names = 95520:95532, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think a two step process is required.  In the previous example, the same `max` values were present in all the ID so the single step condition worked.  Here, we have to filter the `id` first and then need a second filter.  The same as the double slice procedure I mentioned last.  I should have checked the condition with a different dataset.  My bad!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option if we are using numeric index (`which`/`which.max`) will be `slice` from `dplyr`.  Here a double `slice` is needed.  We first subset the 'id' i.e. 'B13639J2' and then subset again for the `max` of 'epnum'
values.

```
 library(dplyr)
 slice(dta, which(id=='B13639J2')) %>%
                   slice(which.max(epnum))
 #        id epnum start
 #1 B13639J2     5  1440
```

Or we group by 'id', `arrange` the 'epnum' in descending order, and `filter` the first row with the specified 'id'.

```
  dta1 <- dta %>% 
             group_by(id) %>% 
             arrange(desc(epnum)) %>%
             filter(id=='B13639J2', row_number()==1L)
```

If we then want to remove this row from the dataset, one option is `anti_join` with the original dataset.

```
  anti_join(dta, dta1)
```

Or by changing the `filter` option this can be done

```
  dta %>%
      group_by(id) %>% 
      arrange(desc(epnum)) %>%
      filter(!(id=='B13639J2' & row_number()==1L))
```

Comment: question : it run perfectly on the sample I give but not on my proper data. I wonder why. Do you mind if I edit my question with the real data I have ?

Comment: @glacomoV sure.  It will be a great help.

Comment: It is very helful thanks, but i need to retreive the `rownumber` in order to delete it.

Comment: so the `row_number()` is suppose to retreive the row ? thanks

Comment: @glacomoV The  row_number() gives the row index.  If there is a group, it will be reset for each group.

Comment: I see - one last thing very sorry - is it possible to do a negative filter on this ` filter(id=='B13639J2', row_number()==1L)`, would it work with ` filter(id!='B13639J2', row_number()==1L)` ? Because I need to get rid of this row. Thanks billion times

Comment: @glacomoV A two step process in `base R` also works i.e. `dta1 <- dta[with(dta, id=='B13639J2'),];dta1[with(dta1, epnum==max(epnum)),]` you can get the row id from there

Comment: @giacomoV  You can use `anti_join` to remove it.

Comment: @giacomoV, You were almost right.  Remove the `,` with `&` in `filter` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

A roundabout base R way of doing this. Temporarily set a copy of all `epnum` values not in your desired group to `NA`, then run `which.max` and drop `-` the resulting row:

```
dta[-which.max(replace(dta$epnum, dta$id != "B13639J2", NA)),]

#            id epnum start
#95520 B13639J1     4   420
#95521 B13639J1     5   425
#95522 B13639J1     6   435
#95523 B13639J1     7   540
#95524 B13639J1     8   570
#95525 B13639J1     9  1000
#95526 B13639J1    10  1310
#95527 B13639J1    11  1325
#95528 B13639J2     1     0
#95529 B13639J2     2   860
#95530 B13639J2     3  1110
#95531 B13639J2     4  1155
```

This is due to `which.max` skipping all `NA` or `NaN` values automatically:

```
which.max(c(NA,1,NaN,2,3))
#[1] 5
```

This doesn't change the row order of the dataset or drop any `rownames` info, and runs quite quickly (about 3s to process a 10M row file over here).

Comment: That is a clever way!

Answer (score 0):

Let me jump in with another possible solution. 
Let me know what you think.

First I create for each variable the `max` of `epnum`

```
dta = dta %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(max = n())
```

Then simply, I `!` the conditions

```
dta[ !(dta$id == 'B13639J2' & (dta$epnum == dta$max)) , ]
```